# Definir varios archivos como FILE

Tags: c

estoy intentando crear un typedef para definir varios FILE, pero no logro que funcione.

Gracias.

```
typedef FILE *texto=NULL;
    texto aleatorio;
    texto mayuscula;
    texto minuscula;
    texto combinado;
}


  

 [Error] typedef 'texto' is initialized (use __typeof__ instead)
```

Comment: Por qué dices que no funciona?

Comment: Solo para ver si entiendo, lo que quieres es que las variables que definas como `texto`, sean un `FILE*` y tengan el valor de `NULL`? Si ese es el caso, el typedef te deja darle el nombre `texto` a el `FILE*`. Pero solo le puede dar un alias a un tipo, no le da un valor default. Talvez lo que quieres hacer lo puedes hacer con macros? Aunque no te lo recomendaria, ya que le quitaria claridad al codigo

Comment: Asi es... Que lastima, pero definiré cada FILE por separado.